# Bluebird EF500 Scanner Disabled after opening Camera

Tags: android, android-camera

I have tried to contact Bluebird support, but I have not had the best luck getting responses in a timely manner, so I am hoping someone might have an answer for me.

In my application I have registered for the intents with kr.co.bluebird.android.bbapi.action.BARCODE_OPEN I have also added the intent filter for DECODING_DATA, REQUEST_SUCCESS, REQUEST_FAILED, STATUS and CALLBACK_PARAMETER.

What I see is that when I get a good scan, I get the BARCODE_CALLBACK_REQUEST_SUCCESS action with a EXTRA_INT_DATA3=100, or success, but I also get EXTRA_INT_DATA3=0.  The reason the 0 value is important, is because that is also what I get when the camera is opened.  So I can't really discern between it being part of the successful scan, and the camera opening and disabling the scanner.

I suspect there is some other filter to add or value to monitor, but I can't find any documentation to help.  Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of it's an Android OS requirement, but when the Camera is opened the scanner connection is always lost.  (Similar to Zebra devices I have used).

I was never able to find anything to determine that the device has closed my connection with the camera, but I was able to modify my application so that any time that my activity had onResume called I would send the intent to open the scanner.  This can be done multiple times without any issue I have seen.  The only thing to be mindful of is that if you call registerReceiver with an IntentFilter multiple times, those are not cleared when the scanner closes. You will start receiving multiple BroadcastReceiver events for each scan.